# PostgreSQL Default Options for "DELETE VIEW"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

According to the PostgreSQL documentation (below) the "Default" option is to "Restrict" the deletion of views.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-dropview.html

I have a application that I'm transferring to pgSQL, I do not have access to source code currently.  Is there a way to change the default behavior from "Restrict" to "Cascade"?

I want a way to change it database/system wide, I realize I can change the SQL my application sends, but I'm not exactly thrilled about doing that.

This is specifically pgSQL-10.

Comment: I will also accept a way to allow PostgreSQL to just move on and drop it leaving orphaned views.

Comment: No the default is baked in.